# reading a file and publishing data to topic

Tags: ros, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> data in the file is of type int [ ] =
> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
>
> Code for Node_1 is as follows:

```
#include<std_msgs/Int32MultiArray.h>
...
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int temp;

  ros::init(argc, argv, "Node_1");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int32MultiArray>("Topic_1",1);

  std_msgs::Int32MultiArray vec;

  ifstream infile("array1.txt");

  while(infile >> temp)
    {
      ROS_INFO("Extracting the elements of the vector from file");
      vec.data.push_back(temp);
    }
  publisher.publish(vec);
  ros::spinOnce();
 
  return 0;
}
```

> Executables are created when I compile
> (using catkin_make)

But when I run this node, the statement

```
"ROS_INFO("Extracting the elements of the vector from file");"
```

is not at all executed

> What could probably be going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227929/reading-a-file-and-publishing-data-to-topic/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing, you have the file in the wrong location.
The file `array1.txt` needs to be in the directory where you execute `rosrun <your_package> <your_node>`, because this is set as the working directory of your executable.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3